# Code to compare one active record with other similar records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code to compare one active record with other records

We have a case where we want to know how many people are leaving, returning and coming to a village.
To get the right results for this case we have to compare each record of the same person with each other, because we want to know if a person has lived in a village before or not.
We have to work with the data as shown in the image (Table now), when the Enddate is null the person is still living in the specified village.

We have to order the records on the table by sql code and calculate the following fields:
-      Departers
-      Returnees
-      Newcomers

Click on the link below for the full description of the case and available data.

[case_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TupTp.jpg)

Comment: No images or links, please. Use formatted text for sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking table.

Comment: Even the link is not accessible. putting on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code which will create a new table in your database, named my_final_table. The code is executed on Microsoft Server.

There are some ambiguous points in the given example for the logic to get your columns, which might need clarification for a better answer. You might not need the column 'Newcomer' if it is the opposite of column 'Returnee'.

The column 'Depart' is created by checking if the column 'Enddate' is blank then it gives "No".
The column 'Returnee' is created by checking the values in the previous line for PersonID and Place.

```
--Check if table exists and drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_final_table', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.my_final_table; 

-- Create example table
SELECT * INTO my_final_table FROM (
SELECT t1.PersonID,
    t1.StartDate,
    t1.Enddate,
    t1.Place,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.[Enddate] IS NULL THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END
    AS Depart,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.PersonID = LAG(t1.PersonID,1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.PersonID, t1.StartDate) AND
        t1.Place = LAG(t1.Place,1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.PersonID, t1.StartDate) THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END
    AS Returnee,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.PersonID = LAG(t1.PersonID,1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.PersonID, t1.StartDate) AND
        t1.Place = LAG(t1.Place,1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.PersonID, t1.StartDate) THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END
    AS Newcomer
FROM [Test_Db].[dbo].[Sheet1$] AS t1) AS A
```